# How can I hide pages from a restricted directory but serve its contents from another URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have administration pages in a folder named `admin/`. These pages require a log in for users to perform actions, but I would like to make it harder to find them. Instead of `admin/`, I want users to access the administration pages from a new folder, e.g. `secret/`. I want to achieve the following:

- when accessing `secret/`, the contents of `admin/` are served.
- when accessing `admin/`, a 404 page is returned.

There are many references to `admin/` in the code, so I was looking to avoid manually finding and replacing those references and somehow achieve these things another way.

I have tried using rewrite rules in .htaccess. In an index.php file, I have also tried checking for the URI and returning a 404 if it contains `admin/`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin/
RewriteRule admin/ secret/ [QSA,L]
```

```php
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) ?? ''
);

if (strpos($uri, 'admin') >= 0) {
    http_response_code(404);
    require '404.php';
    die();}
```

These are what I could think of so far, but neither have helped. What is the correct approach to take for this?

Comment: [Just use password protection instead](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/21985/security-through-obscurity-sto)

Comment: The administration pages are password-protected; users need to log in before performing actions. I want to make it harder for people to guess where those pages are though, which is why I gave the example of a `secret/` folder.

Comment: _"There are many references to admin/ in the code, so I was looking to avoid manually finding and replacing those references"_ - but if you leave those references in front-end code - then any user will be able to _see_ them right there, and therefor your attempt to "hide" where your admin script files are actually located, would be moot. Plus, what difference does it even make, whether I accessed a script via `/admin/foo.php`, or `/secret/foo.php` ...?

Comment: _"What is the correct approach to take for this?"_ - to realize that "security by obscurity" does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code in site root .htaccess:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# externally redirect /admin/* to /secret/*
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+admin/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /secret/%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# internal rewrite from secret/ to admin/
RewriteRule ^secret/(.*) admin/$1 [NC,L]
```